# Python concatenate char to list

Tags: python, concatenation, string-concatenation

The initial input is:

```
input = [60, 20, 50, 70, …, 90]  # ASCII characters
```

I want an output like this:

```
f_paths = ['/ev/path1', '/ev/path2']
```

The ASCII characters are changed to text by concatenating to a string.

```
paths = ''.join([chr(i) for i in input if chr(i) not in '<,'])
```

Now paths string looks like this:

> paths=/notpath/exclude>/ev/path1>/ev/path2>

Now I want to exclude the initial path that is not needed and save the remaining paths

```
start = len(paths[0:paths.find(">")]) + 1
f_paths = []
g=''
for x in paths[start:]:
    if x != '>':
        g = g + x
    else:
        f_paths.append(g)
        g = ''
```

Output is the expected one but there has to be a more optimal way to do the for loop, the problem is I don't know how.

Comment: You can look at dropwhile and takewhile from itertools for iterating with conditions. Something like dropwhile with condition of finding the start char, and then takewhile with condition of the stop char

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do so:

```
paths='/notpath/exclude>/ev/path1>/ev/path2>'
f_paths = paths.split('>')[1:-1]
```

Output:

```
['/ev/path1', '/ev/path2']
```

Comment: @dani you are welcome! please consider to accept the answer by clicking on the tick on the left side of the answer :) https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `regex`:

```
import re

paths = '/notpath/exclude>/ev/path1>/ev/path2>'
print(re.findall(r'(?<=>).*?(?=>)', paths))

# ['/ev/path1', '/ev/path2']
```

Comment: @dani if that troubles you, try the new one (just updated). This now works for any length paths (path1, path2, path3...). :)